# Strip HTML comments from plugins in header/footer

Tags: plugins, headers, footer

Would anyone know a function or how to remove `<!-- plugin inserted stuff-->` from the header and footer so that they won't be visible when viewing source?

Comment: I don't think this is possible - not all browsers show comments either. So I think your choices are to either remove the html comments manually or you can re-write the comments you need as PHP comments instead since those aren't visible in the source, but still visible in the files for documentation purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible. I have tested it on my own server, but it might be better to just remove the comments yourself, or put them as php comments regardless.

I only demo'd this with header.php, and used the code from [this page](http://davidwalsh.name/remove-html-comments-php) to assist me.

First of all, take the entire contents of your **header.php** (or whatever other file you want to remove comments from) and put them into a new file like **header2.php** - call it whatever you want, just remember it for later.
Then, in your now empty **header.php**, put the following php code:

```
<?php
// Remove unwanted HTML comments
ob_start();
include 'header2.php';
$newheader = ob_get_clean();
remove_html_comments($newheader);
function remove_html_comments($content) {
    echo preg_replace('/<!--(.|\s)*?-->/', '', $content);
}
?>
```

**Remember**: If you named your new file something other than header2.php, change it's name accordingly on line 4 of the code!

It stores the response from your old **header.php** in an [output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631388/read-echoed-output-from-another-php-file), then runs the nifty code that we got from the post I linked to earlier, and echoes the output.

This produced the desired affect, and the echoed code still showed stuff like what page I was on, etc - enjoy! (Ps. Use at own risk)

As suggested by another member, you could just name **header2.php** to something along the lines of **header-custom.php** which in effect lets you use **get_header(custom)**, instead of having to use an output buffer (I think... not too sure, haven't tested). This is probably a more correct method of naming, at the very least it might help if you're making a theme to sell it.

Comment: Just name your new file header-custom.php and call it like `get_header('custom');`